# After installing urllib3 I cannot go back to urllib

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

This is a strange problem, where I `pip` installed `urllib3` and then wanted to use urllib again, however the method that I called seems no longer available. Is there some kind of latching that is going on, because this code worked for the install of urllib3.

```
from urllib import quote_plus
ImportError: cannot import name 'quote_plus'
```

Comment: I don't know what is going on in your environment. If you are using Python3 that never should have worked, because `quote_plus` is under `urllib.parse` now. Furthermore, I also brought up a python 2 virtualenv to test as well, and `from urllib import quote_plus` worked.

Comment: @idjaw I can see urllib3 is split also, does quote_plus exist in urllib3 too?